# NodeJS validate that a private key matches a X.509 certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, x509

Given a private key and a X.509 certificate (no RSA), I want to confirm that:

- The private key is "valid".
- It matches the certificate.

This validation would run in nodejs.

Example of valid private key (don't worry, testing purposes):

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgSVkfyOqQ4E6No+v6
h/wotfYuGqiqierJ2YXx2v3rP1GhRANCAASMlEMAwv9jf8FAKDAxrnPGWVGBBzbD
wt3VQrrM5i/DOwCzF1XH7v6iYbvpYe9P0Qvf5ndqYYBklqLkXHAR37Vz
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Example of matching certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: The common technique is to compare the (hash or fingerprint over) the modulus. These need to be the same in the private key and signed public key within the certificate. The modulus is unique for the key pair. That's the technique, maybe you could think up some code in NodeJS to actually perform the comparison, as I'm not an expert in NodeJS. Oh, almost forgot; simply signing something and performing the verification should also work. Or - if the cert allows it (key usage), encrypt / decrypt of course.

Comment: So far all my Google searches of "modulus" showed me openssl commands. Is the algorithm simple enough to implement in javascript?
I also like your idea of encrypting and decrypting. If someone can elaborate as an answer...

Comment: @Marteen Bodewes you mentioned "if the cert allows it". Is there a way to check that? (cert example is included in the question).
And yes of course I am trying myself, I'm having a hard time so far.

Comment: I think a lot of the examples I found online assume "RSA"

Comment: Paste the base 64 of the cert into https://lapo.it/asn1js. You'll find that just the a single (first) bit is set when looking for "key usage". You can find the meaning of it [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3). If key usage is only set for one specific operation then the others are disallowed. You can of course ignore it and use encrypt / decrypt anyway, but that's too much "hacking it" for comfort; sign / verify are more likely to work. By the way, https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/issues/297 seems to support retrieving the public key and modulus.

Comment: Assuming I'm OK with simply using an openssl wrapper for NodeJS. I see I can extract the public key from both the private key and the certificate, and they look the same. Is that "safe" enough?

Comment: Well, they should *be* the same, not just *look* the same (the structure and the public exponent are likely to be the same even for different key pairs). But yes, both include the modulus, and commonly the modulus in the private key is only stored once. So a comparison of the modulus or indeed the entire public key should indeed suffice.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I don't know if you noticed but this is an elliptic curve keypair, so "modulus" isn't very useful.

Comment: @JamesKPolk does it mean that comparing their public keys won’t work? Or just modulus?

Comment: Comparing the public keys still works, but what constitutes a public key is different than for RSA. For an elliptic curve the modulus is not unique, it is part if something called the *domain parameters* that define the elliptic curve and thus are shared by all keys. The public key is just a point on the curve, given as either an (x,y) coordinate pair or sometime just the x coordinate.

Comment: As JamesKPolk wrote, EC public key constitutes a different thing than with RSA, but the suggestion from MaartenBodewes is also right - you may use the private key to sign something (your cert only points to digital signature as key usage) and verify that.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Ah, nuts. Well, OK, yeah, sign / verify works and should be compatible with the key usage. Stupid, I never noticed the EC algorithm even when I opened in the ASN.1 decoder, I just assumed a small RSA key when Nathan said: "no worries, just for testing purposes". My brain translated that into: "small key, but that doesn't matter". I'll tell it not to make such deductions anymore :)

Comment: Ok so we agree sign/verify is best if I can figure out the implementation. James wrote “Comparing the public keys still works but...”.  What do you mean by “works”? If I understand correctly, you mean I could potential get a false positive? The incorrect private key could still give me the same public key as the certificate?

Comment: Guys, see the top answer in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-can-you-check-if-a-private-key-and-certificate-match-in-openssl-with-ecdsa . (1A) seems to imply that it's OK to compare the public keys?

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to create a secure context, using the built in node api. It will throw if the certificates don't match:

```js
import tls from 'tls';

function testCertAndKeyMatch (cert, key) {
  try {
    tls.createSecureContext({ cert, key });
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ERR_OSSL_X509_KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH') {
      return false;
    }
    throw error; 
  }
}
```

You can use it like:

```js
const cert = fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const key = fs.readFileSync('./certs/key.pem', 'utf8');
const isMatch = testCertAndKeyMatch(cert, key);
```